# Windows "Settings" ("Managed By Windows") insane power usage

Tags: windows-10, battery-life, microsoft-surface

I just rebooted Windows, and it suggested I look at how much battery I was using on the Surface Book, telling me that "running too many applications will reduce your battery life".

So it popped me into the "Settings" app on the Battery Usage Page...and guess who's at the top (by a huge margin)?  Settings itself.

[image: settings-managed-by-windows-at-72%]

The smaller numbers sort of reflect my sense of usage.  Changing "Time:" to a week study drops it to 50%, and Chrome shows up at 22%.

The machine is plugged into the wall except on accident.  Sometimes the little magnet slips and I put it back in as soon as I notice.  I haven't noticed any particular spike in the Task Manager or running the fan for the "Settings" app.

How is this to be interpreted?  If the power cable slips out and is only temporarily out for a few seconds, and then gets plugged back in, does the act of the power transition trigger Settings to run in order to adapt the power profile, and it runs something relatively heavy duty which would lead it to have this large spike in accounting?

Wondering how I'm supposed to interpret this, and if anyone else (maybe who tends to operate plugged into AC power) has seen a similar distribution.

Answer (score 0):

If you only just now went onto battery from mains power, Settings may have been the only app to have had time to use the battery in the last 10 seconds.

Or if you were on battery during the whole boot, it could be picking up system use in that icon.

Try again in half an hour or so...